# How Domain Plays a Role for a Vector Field to be Conservative

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I attempt to understand the identification and applications of differential forms in vector calculus from Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* (2nd edition) (page no. 43). The author states the following preposition.

> **Proposition C.** *On $\mathbb{R}^3$, a vector field $\textbf{F}$ is the gradient of some scalar function $f$ if and only if $\text{curl} \, \textbf{F} = 0$.*

If I have understood correctly, then this Proposition C describes the following two conditions:

- **Condition 1:** $\textbf{F}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$,
- **Condition 2:** $\text{curl} \, \textbf{F} = 0$,

which imply $\textbf{F} = \text{grad} \, f$, where $f: \mathbb{R}^3  \to \mathbb{R}$.

**My Question:** Could you please supply an example of a vector field $\textbf{F}: U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\text{curl} \, \textbf{F} = 0$ such that for $U = \mathbb{R}^3$, $\textbf{F}$ can be written as the gradient of some scalar function but for some $U \neq \mathbb{R}^3$, $\textbf{F}$ can not be written as the gradient of some scalar function?

Please note that the example supplied in the book chooses a vector field $\textbf{F}$ which is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$. As a result, I don't see clearly how **Condition 1** plays its role.

Comment: Such a thing is impossible. The example in the book takes the correct route - removing the "defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ condition" shows that the statement is no longer an "if and only if" - it only works in one direction (gradient implies zero curl).

Answer (score 1):

There can be no such example, since on $U$ $\mathbf F$ could be written as the gradient of the same scalar function (restricted to $U$).

Rather, the condition is necessary because there are vector fields with zero curl that are not defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$ and are not the gradient of a scalar function. An example is afforded by

$$
\mathbf F(\mathbf r)=\frac1{x^2+y^2}\pmatrix{-y\\x\\0}\;,
$$

defined everywhere except on the $z$ axis, which has zero curl but is not the gradient of a scalar function since its line integral along a circle around the $z$ axis is non-zero.